# background property does not work when I use the URL that already belongs to another website

Tags: html, css

I'm using header section and adding the background image using background-image property. the link I'm using belongs to another website. The code that belongs to CSS is mentioned below.

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/assets2/content-marketing/business-encyclopedia/spiral-3afd090ee00a1c9465e909ceac5172e3685877782fbbc22e119d3a3292739d13.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: What is the error you get in devtools console? I think its [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), try to remove `https` from the URL so its `//cdn.shopify.com/assets2/content-marketing/busi.....`

Comment: There is no error showing on devtool. Besides, If I try to use some other website that's link does work perfectly but I can't understand what's wrong with this website.

Comment: Removing http from the URL does not work as well. Is it possible that the website that I'm using isn't allowing me to use its images publically? If so, is there any quick way to guess it without reading the policies of the website?

Answer (score 1):

@Nouman Ahmad Your code is working. It's just that the image is white. If you add a background-color black, you'll be able to see the image. And maybe you'll have to specify a height in px for your header too.